# Error en mi consulta con jdbc java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Amigos, un gusto saludarlos, tengo un problema que me tiene loco y la verdad ya hice muchas cosas para poder solucionar este error, lo que pasa es que estoy consultando una tabla y validando con cadenas de `jsons`, aquí no tengo problemas, el problema es en mi ejecución de mi consulta que le estoy pasando un parámetro para validar ese valor con los `json` de lo que me traiga del `query` y pasarlo a un `jtable` los valores de la segunda columna, pero en problema es que me arroja este error:

```
16/07/2019 00:14:40 <ERROR> <DataSvcAccess.read(queryCode)> <Error de Sistema>
Causa asociada: com.covaf.server.security.SecDataException: Error al ejecutar read.
com.covaf.server.security.SecDataException: Error al ejecutar read.
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RMIConnection.EXCEPTION_ORIGINATES_FROM_THE_REMOTE_SERVER(RMIConnection.java:1558)
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RMIConnection.invokeMethod(RMIConnection.java:1511)
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:55)
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RecoverableRemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RecoverableRemoteInvocationHandler.java:22)
    at com.evermind.server.ejb.StatelessSessionRemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(StatelessSessionRemoteInvocationHandler.java:50)
    at __Proxy3.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.covaf.client.shell.DataSvcAccess.read(DataSvcAccess.java:303)
    at com.covaf.client.shell.ProcImportaDerechos.procesaJsonFiles(ProcImportaDerechos.java:530)
    at com.covaf.client.shell.ProcImportaDerechos.access$8(ProcImportaDerechos.java:439)
    at com.covaf.client.shell.ProcImportaDerechos$ImportacionArchivo.ImportaArchivoDeDatos(ProcImportaDerechos.java:916)
    at com.covaf.client.shell.ProcImportaDerechos$ImportacionArchivo.construct(ProcImportaDerechos.java:863)
    at com.covaf.client.shell.SwingWorker$2.run(SwingWorker.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.jonima.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: AbstractTable.read(null); nested exception is: 
    com.jonima.jdbc.core.UncategorizedSQLException: (JdbcTemplate.query(psc) with PreparedStatementCreator [PreparedStatementCreatorFactory.PreparedStatementCreatorImpl: sql={ select t.tipo_derecho , e.equiv_in , t.desc_derecho   from equiv_tipos_derechos e   left join v_tipos_derechos t  on t.tipo_derecho = e.equiv_tipo_derecho  where e.equiv_in = ? }: params={CashDividend}]): encountered SQLException [Invalid column name]; nested exception is: 
    java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at com.jonima.table.AbstractTable.read(AbstractTable.java:400)
    at com.jonima.table.AbstractTable.read(AbstractTable.java:351)
    at com.jonima.table.AbstractTable.read(AbstractTable.java:508)
    at com.covaf.server.security.DataServicesBean.read(DataServicesBean.java:591)
    at DataServices_StatelessSessionBeanWrapper8.read(DataServices_StatelessSessionBeanWrapper8.java:1412)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RMICallHandler.run(RMICallHandler.java:119)
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RMICallHandler.run(RMICallHandler.java:48)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.PooledExecutor$Worker.run(PooledExecutor.java:803)
```

Y este es mi código que estoy usando por la cual surge error de arriba, ya revisé todo lo que podría estar mal y pues no mas no sé que sería:

```
public static final int QUERY_DERECHOS_TIPOS = 3;//JJ

case VTiposDerechosDataBean.QUERY_DERECHOS_TIPOS://JJ
            sql.append(" select t.tipo_derecho , e.equiv_in , t.desc_derecho  " +
                    " from equiv_tipos_derechos e  " +
                    " left join v_tipos_derechos t  on t.tipo_derecho = e.equiv_tipo_derecho " +
                    " where e.equiv_in = ? "
            );
            System.out.println("Query22222...: " + sql.toString());
            //campos = new Vector();
            campos.add("tipo_derecho");
            campos.add("equiv_in");
            campos.add("desc_derecho");
            //System.out.println("Campos...: " + campos);
            break;
```

El siguiente método es el parámetro que le estoy pasando para que me realice la consulta:

```
case VTiposDerechosDataBean.QUERY_DERECHOS_TIPOS:
               //operation.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.INTEGER));
               operation.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR));
               //operation.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(Types.VARCHAR));

             break;
```

Mi consulta `sql` es la siguiente:

```
SELECT T.TIPO_DERECHO,E.EQUIV_IN,T.DESC_DERECHO FROM V_TIPOS_DERECHOS T left join COVACK_PROCESOS.EQUIV_TIPOS_DERECHOS E ON T.TIPO_DERECHO=E.EQUIV_TIPO_DERECHO
WHERE E.EQUIV_IN= ?;
```

El siguiente código mando a llamar mi consulta:

```
 String tipoEvento =(String) jsonObjectArchivo.get("tipoEvento");

 List paramsConsulta1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   paramsConsulta1.add(tipoEvento);
   System.out.println(paramsConsulta1);
   //paramsConsulta1.add(serie);
  // paramsConsulta1.add(isin);
 //java.util.List res1= svc.read(beanD, DerechosCorporativosDataBean.QUERY_DERECHOS_TIPOS, paramsConsulta1);
   java.util.List res1= svc.read(beanVTipos, VTiposDerechosDataBean.QUERY_DERECHOS_TIPOS, paramsConsulta1);
System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxvvvvv---"+res1);
 //Object tipoEvento = jsonObjectArchivo.get("tipoEvento");

if(res1!=null && res1.size()>0){
    for (int i = 0; i < res1.size(); i++) {
         Vector resFila =(Vector)res1.get(i); 
            if(resFila.get(1).equals(tipoEvento)){
                 objectVector[3] = resFila.get(2);
                agregarValores(objectVector);
            }

    }
}
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, si algo no queda claro háganmelo saber por favor, quedo al pendiente, saludos y excelente día :)

Comment: buenas compañero @cratus666jose, una consulta veo que te emite el siguiente error en el mensaje `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name`, as podido realizar esa misma consulta de forma directa a tu base de datos ? quiero decir el query `select t.tipo_derecho , e.equiv_in , t.desc_derecho   from equiv_tipos_derechos e   left join v_tipos_derechos t  on t.tipo_derecho = e.equiv_tipo_derecho  where e.equiv_in = ?` incluido con el parámetros que le estas pasando

Comment: Si, todo eso si sale bien, es el problema que en el developer si ejecuta pero desde el java no :(

Comment: Concuerdo con @Nicethunder, el error dice que una de las columnas en lista no existe en las tablas, revisa nuevamente. Una sola letra distinta hace la diferencia.

Comment: Hola amigos, estuve probando, y si, efectivamente es el nombre de la columna, pero ya es problema de los alias que estoy poniendo en mi consulta, hay alguna manera de tomar esos alias y que el java no le duela??